# Why are some posts text grey or dim?

Tags: support, answers

Just curious as to why some posts appear grey or dim compared to other posts?

[image: grey]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an increasing negative score, answers are faded out to show that they are not well received and thus of less importance than others—or just plain wrong.

I think the lightest grey you can get is at -6 but I could be wrong.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the quick reply :)